# What is the sum from 0 to infinity of the reciprocal of the rising factorial with both parameters having the index as the argument?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n)_n}$$

where $(x)_n$ is the Pochhammer symbol (rising factorial), defined as:

$$\frac{\Gamma(x+n)}{\Gamma(x)} = \frac{(x+n-1)!}{(x-1)!}$$
?

I'm really more interested in the process of finding the closed form because just plugging it in to Wolfram Alpha is easy enough.

Comment: This is confusing... Isn't this the same as $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac 1{i!}$?  Perhaps you can write out the first several terms so it is easier to distinguish what the differences are?

Comment: @abiessu It's really just (n-1)!/(2n-1)!

Answer (score 2):

*One possible solution*

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n)_n}$$
$$\int f(x)\,dx=x \, _2F_2\left(1,1;\frac{1}{2},2;\frac{x}{4}\right)$$
$$\frac d{dx}\int f(x)\,dx=-\frac{1}{4} e^{x/4} \sqrt{x} \left(2 \sqrt{\pi }
   \left(1-\text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{4
   e^{-x/4}}{\sqrt{x}}-2 \sqrt{\pi }\right)$$ Expand and simplify
$$f(x)=1+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } e^{x/4} \sqrt{x}
   \text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)$$ Now, compute $f(1)$.

Comment: wow i think i'm in over my head here. how do you even find that integral and what even is that F function with all the subscripts

Comment: As I wrote, this is *one possible* solution using hypergeometric functions.